# How to change IP when /etc/network/interface file is missing?

Tags: 12.04, server, static-ip

I just installed 12.04 Server. After my first login, I saw the IP and it is dynamic (I guess). I tried to change it by `sudo vi /etc/network/interface` but this file is blank.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 5):

You typed:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interface
```

You should have typed this:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

*You forgot the **s**.*

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses Network Manager to manage the network configuration.

Run `nm-connection-editor` to set a static IP.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from:
[Create a Static IP from the Command Line](http://usefulubuntu.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/create-static-ip-from-command-line.html)

---

***Basically, steps needed are:***

Find out you current settings:

```
ifconfig eth0
```

Edit **/etc/network/interfaces** to meet your requirements.

Look for these two line:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Change them to instead be: (*example IP addresses*)

```
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.130
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

Then **re-start** your server.

It should now be using: **192.168.0.130**

Comment: 12.04 also needs `dns-nameservers 192.168.0.x` as they changed how resolv.conf works.

Comment: Sorry, I cribbed from my old notes for **10.04 LTS** server.

Comment: `ifconfig` is kind of obsolete now